# custom text in "list of figures"

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using a template for writing a long document. It automatically creates a list of figures at the start. In the list every entry is nothing but a caption of the figure. In   some figures caption string is too long and it doesn't look good. How can I put custom strings in "list of figures"?

Comment: Use the optional argument of `caption`: `\caption[<custom string>]{<regular caption>}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\caption` has two arguments - one optional and the other mandatory. The contents of optional argument (which is enclosed within `[]`) is used for the list of figures (if given). If you want to put custom (short) description in the list of figures, use it in the optional argument like:

```
\caption[<custom string>]{<regular caption>}
```

A sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{some section}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption[Short caption]{Here comes the long caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]